# Symfony lock component is allowing to the same cron withour releasing the previous job lock

Tags: php, symfony4, symfony-lock

We recently started to use the Symfony lock component to prevent 2 cron job execution simultaneously. We are using php7.2 & Symfony4.4 Here is the example

```
class TestCommand extends Command
{
  use LockableTrait;

  protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
  {
    try {
        if (!$this->lock(self::$defaultName)) 
        {
            $output->writeln('Previous job is still running...');
            return false;
        }
        // our logic
  }
}
```

We tested & everything was fine, however in some situations it is not working.  At the same time, 2 TestCommands are running, we could not reproduce the issue. we did some analysis, but no luck

It will be really helpful if I could get a solution/clue to resolve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: What store do you use for locks? Do you run commands on the same machine?

Comment: for few commands, we use SemaphoreStore & for a few RedisStore. 
Yes we run commands on the same machine